# Complexity of: One matrix is row/col permutation of another matrix

Tags: matrix, complexity-theory, permutation

1. Given two m x n matrices A and B whose elements belong to a set S.
   Problem: Can the rows and columns of A be permuted to give B?
   What is the complexity of algorithms to solve this problem?
   Determinants partially help (when m=n): a necessary condition is that det(A) = +/- det(B).
2. Also allow A to contain "don't cares" that match any element of B.
3. Also, if S is finite allow permutations of elements of A.

This is not homework - it is related to the solved 17x17 puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

See below example of permuting rows and columns of a matrix:

[image]

Observe the start matrix and end matrix. All elements in a row or column are retained its just that their order has changed. Also the change in relative positions is uniform across rows and columns

eg. see 1 in start matrix and end matrix. Its row has elements 12, 3 and 14 along with it. Also its column has 5, 9 and 2 along with it. This is maintained across the transformations.

Based on this fact I am putting forward this basic algo to find for a given matrix A, can its rows and columns of A be permuted to give matrix B.

```
 1. For each row in A, sort all elements in the row. Do same for B.
 2. Sort all rows of A (and B) based on its columns. ie. if row1 is {5,7,16,18} and row2 is {2,4,13,15}, then put row2 above row1
 3. Compare resultant matrix A' and B'. 
 4. If both equal, then do (1) and (2) but for columns on ORIGINAL matrix A & B instead of rows.
 5. Now compare resultant matrix A'' and B''
```

Comment: You cannot sort rows in isolation, else {{1,2},{3,4}} will be equivalent to {{1,2},{4,3}}.

Comment: if you are using array to represent the matrix, then it will be easy to do in place sorting. I agree that after sorting rows {{1,2},{3,4}} will be equivalent to {{1,2},{4,3}} but their difference will be caught later while comparing sorted columns. You can dry run the logic and check that.

Comment: Note that in point #4, the sorting on columns is done on ORIGINAL matrices A and B. The sorted rows are not processed thereafter.

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable! Now for a proof (or a counterexample?)

Comment: Here's a counterexample. A = {{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,0}} and B = {{0,1,0},{1,1,0},{0,0,1}}.